# React JS Data Table getting r.slice is not a function error message

Tags: reactjs

I was having some problem when trying to use Data Table in React JS.

My customized Data Table js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import withFixedColumns from 'react-table-hoc-fixed-columns';
import ReactTable from 'react-table';

import Paging from 'components/common/pagination';
import ShowList from 'components/common/showlist';

const ReactTableFixedColumns = withFixedColumns(ReactTable);

class DataTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      page: 0,
      pageSize: props.pageSize || 5,
      data: props.data || [],
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    // const check = !_.isEqual(props.data, state.data);
    const check = props.data !== state.data;
    if (check) {
      return {
        page: 0,
        data: props.data || [],
      };
    }
    return null;
  }

  onChangePageSize = (size) => {
    this.setState({
      pageSize: size.value,
      page: 0,
    });
  };

  onChangePage = (number) => {
    this.setState({
      page: number,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { page, pageSize, data } = this.state;
    const { columns, getTrProps, getTdProps, showListHidden, title, rightTitle, tableClassName, showListPosition, containerClassName, rightHeaderContent, defaultPageSize } = this.props;
    const finalPageSize = Math.max(Math.min(pageSize, data.length), defaultPageSize || 3);
    const finalData = data.slice(page * finalPageSize, (page + 1) * finalPageSize);

    return (
      <div className={containerClassName}>
        {(!showListHidden || title) && (
          <ShowList
            pageSize={pageSize}
            totalItems={data.length}
            onChangePageSize={this.onChangePageSize}
            showListHidden={showListHidden}
            title={title}
            rightTitle={rightTitle}
            showListPosition={showListPosition}
            rightHeaderContent={rightHeaderContent}
          />
        )}
        <ReactTableFixedColumns
          className={`react__table ${tableClassName}`}
          columns={columns}
          data={finalData}
          pageSize={finalPageSize}
          showPagination={false}
          sortable={false}
          getTrProps={getTrProps}
          resizable={false}
          getTdProps={getTdProps}
        />
        <Paging number={page} totalPages={data.length / pageSize} onClickPager={this.onChangePage} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DataTable;
```

My component js that passed in a populated array into the Data Table:

```
const columns = [
  {
    Header: 'Old Received Date',
    accessor: 'oldReceivedDate',
    minWidth: tableColumnWidth.lg,
  },
  {
    Header: 'New Received Date',
    accessor: 'newReceivedDate',
    minWidth: tableColumnWidth.lg,
  },
];

render() {
console.log(auditList);
<div className="paddingBottom50 tabsContainer">
<div>
   <DataTable data={auditList || []} columns={columns} />
</div>
</div>
}
```

I tried to print out auditList, and managed to get the following:

```
auditList: Array(1)
0:
barcodeId: "001333-167"
createdBy: "analyst"
createdDate: "2022-07-07T15:39:06"
inspectionId: "102977-158223"
newCertificationDate: "2022-05-05T13:36:00"
newFirstExaminedDate: "2021-09-04T13:36:00"
newIdentifiedBy: "Analyst"
newReceivedBy: "Admin"
newReceivedDate: "2021-09-04T13:36:00"
oldCertificationDate: "2022-05-05T13:36:00"
oldFirstExaminedDate: "2022-05-05T13:36:00"
oldIdentifiedBy: "Analyst"
oldReceivedBy: "Admin"
oldReceivedDate: "2022-05-05T13:34:00"
updatedBy: "analyst"
updatedDate: "2022-07-07T15:39:06
```

However, the page is throwing below error after the console.log():

```
TypeError: r.slice is not a function
    at n.value (116.21668fc3.chunk.js:1:3750)
    at Di (11.9c4a903c.chunk.js:1:1800861)
    at Ii (11.9c4a903c.chunk.js:1:1800654)
    at mc (11.9c4a903c.chunk.js:1:1836565)
    at ls (11.9c4a903c.chunk.js:1:1827780)
    at cs (11.9c4a903c.chunk.js:1:1827705)
    at Jc (11.9c4a903c.chunk.js:1:1824714)
    at 11.9c4a903c.chunk.js:1:1776099
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (11.9c4a903c.chunk.js:1:1851680)
    at Xa (11.9c4a903c.chunk.js:1:1775808)
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:4026
```

Any ideas why is it so? I tried to check with existing js that uses the Data Table, all of them are working fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your reason for using the lifecycle method `getDerivedStateFromProps` is not clear, and it is probably not achieving what you want it to (to update the state  when `props.data` changes? )

As per [React official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

> This method exists for rare use cases where the state depends on changes in props over time. For example, it might be handy for implementing a  component that compares its previous and next children to decide which of them to animate in and out.

Instead, why not just consume `data` directly from the props in `render()`. Any change in data passed in by the parent component will then trigger a re-render anyway.

```
render() {    
    const { data } = this.props;
    [...]
}
```

Comment: @SiminL Hi I am not supposed to change the Data Table js as its used by many other existing components. Do you have any ideas on what am I supposed to change in the component js to resolve the issue?